# Cloud function that makes an API request works (204) when run as a script on local not via testing or functions-framework (401)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, functions-framework

I'm working on a Google cloud gen1 non http triggered cloud function and I would like to test it locally before deploying.

The function makes an api request to github actions. It works locally with a 204 response when I just run the script on it's own. However, when I try to either run from the GCP functions UI using the testing tab, or via functions-framework, I get a 401 error.

Billing is enabled for the project.

Variable `PAT` is in .env file on local, on GCP it's a secret manifested as an env var.

The trigger for the function occurs once every 24 hours and I did notice that the function ran via the pub/sub trigger. I just cannot invoke the function locally or via the UI during the course of development and testing (the 401 response).

Here's main.py:

```
import requests
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# globals, reads .env if present, else reads host env vars
load_dotenv()
OWNER = os.environ['OWNER']
REPO = os.environ['REPO']
EVENT_TYPE = os.environ['EVENT_TYPE']
PAT = os.environ['PAT']

# the function
def requestGHA(PAT=PAT, OWNER=OWNER, REPO=REPO, EVENT_TYPE=EVENT_TYPE):

    # Set up the headers for the API request
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/vnd.github+json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {PAT}",
    }

    # Set up the URL for the API request
    url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/dispatches" 

    # Set up the payload for the API request
    payload = {
        "event_type": EVENT_TYPE,
        "client_payload": {
            "db_schema": "dev"
        }
    }

    # Make the API request
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    
    return str(response.status_code)
```

If I run this in a python console and then type `requestGHA()`, everything works with a 204 response. But when I try e.g. via functions framework:

```
$ functions-framework --target requestGHA --debug
 * Serving Flask app "requestGHA" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://192.168.0.33:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with watchdog (inotify)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 103-819-696
```

After running this if I visit http://localhost:8080/ I see 401.

Why can't I run my cloud function locally?

Comment: I haven't used the Python functions framework myself, but every example I've seen has either a "request" parameter or an event-oriented parameter. (I also don't know whether parameter defaults work in the functions framework.) I would get rid of all the actual code to start with, and just try to get an "empty" function that just logs that it was called. You can then make that function call your `requestGHA` function.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't understand why but your suggestion solved my problem! I added this at the end of main.py `def bla(st):
    
    st = requestGHA()
    
    return(st)` then I ran functions farmework with function bla. WHy is this working?!

Comment: Presumably because the Functions Framework expects a parameter for the HTTP request, or the event. (That's certainly the case in the .NET Functions Framework, but there you have to implement an interface anyway, so it's all rather more statically bound...)

Comment: @jonSkeet but didn’t my original func already have params? PAT, OWNER etc? Just trying to understand it. All I’ve done is call the original function in a new “parent” function right?! :/

Comment: It had a bunch of parameters, yes - but how would you expect the Functions Framework to know what to do with them? The Functions Framework has some input (a CloudEvent, a legacy event or an HTTP request) and needs to call a function, providing that input. So it needs to find a function with a suitable signature. You might want to file an issue on the repo (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python) to clarify the requirements of the target function.